# Trouble Installing Babel for Nimrod

Tags: ubuntu, nim-lang, nimrod-babel

I'm having trouble installing `babel`.

First I downloaded everything from github,

```
connor@vader:~$ git clone https://github.com/nimrod-code/babel.git
```

and then I tried installing using,

```
connor@vader:~$ nimrod c -r babel/src/babel install
```

but then I got this,

```
config/nimrod.cfg(36, 11) Hint: added path: '/home/connor/.babel/libs/' [Path]
Hint: used config file '/opt/nimrod/config/nimrod.cfg' [Conf]
Hint: used config file 'babel/src/babel.nimrod.cfg' [Conf]
Hint: system [Processing]
Hint: babel [Processing]
Hint: httpclient [Processing]
Hint: sockets [Processing]
Hint: os [Processing]
Hint: strutils [Processing]
Hint: parseutils [Processing]
Hint: times [Processing]
Hint: posix [Processing]
Hint: openssl [Processing]
Hint: parseurl [Processing]
Hint: strtabs [Processing]
Hint: hashes [Processing]
Hint: parseopt [Processing]
Hint: osproc [Processing]
Hint: streams [Processing]
Hint: pegs [Processing]
Hint: unicode [Processing]
Hint: tables [Processing]
Hint: math [Processing]
Hint: json [Processing]
Hint: lexbase [Processing]
Hint: algorithm [Processing]
Hint: packageinfo [Processing]
Hint: parsecfg [Processing]
/home/connor/babel/src/babelpkg/packageinfo.nim(4, 14) Error: cannot open 'version'
```

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, and Nimrod 0.9.2 is installed at `/opt/nimrod/`. My first instinct was to do `sudo chmod a+rwx /opt/nimrod`, but that didn't fix anything. Do you guys have any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

The git version of babel depends on the git version of nimrod. The stable 0.9.2 version doesn't look into the same paths and subdirectories and fails to find the `version` module found in the `babelpkg` subdirectory. You can explicitly mention this directory for inclusion with a command line switch:

```
cd babel
nimrod --path:src/babelpkg c -r src/babel  install
```

However, it will fail due to dependency versions:

```
Installing babel-0.2.0
Unsatisfied dependency: nimrod (>= 0.9.3)
Error: execution of an external program failed
```

Unfortunately the babel repository doesn't use tags other than 0.2, so there is no way to know which past version could be checked out to and compatible with nimrod 0.9.2. Your only chance seems to be to upgrade to the git version of nimrod.

Comment: I tried installing the git version of nimrod by following the instructions on GitHub, but I got this error: `compiler/semdata.nim(261, 16) Error: 'getSysType' cannot be passed to procvar FAILURE` after executing `./koch boot -d:release`. I thought that maybe it was because I didn't delete my previous symbolic link, so I redid everything after deleting the old link, but that wasn't it.

Comment: The build farm at (http://build.nimrod-lang.org) shows troubles with the last commit on non linux platforms, try to check out version 762e343e170bdb2b0c3a46ed3ca081a9756a5ed7 which is just 10 days old and works for me on macosx.

Comment: Okay, I'll get on that as soon as I get home. I'm currently using Ubuntu  12.04.4.

Comment: I recall problems in the past with Ubuntu distributions, might be worth reporting the problem at https://github.com/Araq/Nimrod/issues to check if there is a problem with this distribution.